# Invoke method as closure

Tags: groovy, closures

My understanding of the Groovy operator `.&` is that it converts a method call to a closure. Therefore it seems like the following code (which can be run in the [Groovy console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)) should work:

```
class Foo {
  def method(def param) {
    param + 10
  }
}

def invokeClosure = {Closure closure ->
   return closure.call()
}

def f = new Foo()
invokeClosure f.&method(6)
```

Of course if I change the last line to

```
invokeClosure {f.method(6)}
```

it works fine, but what's wrong with my understanding of the `.&` operator?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When converting a method to a closure using **.&** notation you leave off the parameters.  f.&method(6) is the same as calling f.method(6) which will return 16, so in your example you are passing 16 into invokeClosure and not a closure.  Which causes the following exception since the Integer class doesn't have a call method:

**Exception thrown: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call()**

Below passes a method pointer for f.method into invokeClosure and would be how you would typically use .&.

```
class Foo {
  def method(def param) {
    param + 10
  }
}

def invokeClosure = {Closure closure ->
   return closure.call(6) // can leave off .call
}

def f = new Foo()
invokeClosure f.&method
```

As you pointed out the following will work:

```
invokeClosure {f.method(6)}
```

That's because you are passing a closure that takes no parameters so that's why closure.call() works in that case.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking I think `{f.method(6)}` is a closure that takes one parameter whereas `{-> f.method(6)}` is a closure that takes no params. Great answer though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `invokeClosure f.&method.curry(6)` instead. This is a closure which could be called without parameters

Answer (score 0):

The example above could also be extended to take the parameter as argument into the invokeClosure. That would give you the expected result and syntax.

```
class Foo {
  def method(def param) {
    param + 10
  }
}

def invokeClosure = {Closure closure, def parameter ->
   return closure.call(parameter) 
}

def f = new Foo()
invokeClosure f.&method, 6
```